# How does this query work to split csv into rows in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I am using sql-server 2012

here is the query

```
drop table #t
create table #t(id int,name varchar(10))
insert into #t values(1,'a,b,c'),(2,'d,e')

select A.id,split.a.value('.','varchar(10)') as string 
from 
    (select id,cast('<M>'+replace([name],',','</M><M>')+'</M>' as xml) as string from #t) as A  cross apply string.nodes('/M') as split(a)
```

I am trying to get the logic of query used here,but unable to understand how it is working?

can some body guide me in making understand the

logic in the `cast()` clause and `split.a.value()`

Answer (score 3):

The Cast clause converts the string into an XML fragment to be consumed later by the 'nodes' method. If you run just the subquery:

```
select id,cast('<M>'+replace([name],',','</M><M>')+'</M>' as xml) as string 
from #t
```

You get the results below:

```
id  string
1   <M>a</M><M>b</M><M>c</M>
2   <M>d</M><M>e</M>
```

The Node method splits the XML data into relational form. To oversimplify, the Nodes method gives you a table 'Split' with a column 'A'. The Value method finally converts the value in the node to a varchar for projection:
(split.A.value('.','varchar(10)') can be interpreted as Table.Column.Value(root to varchar(10)).

Refer the following links for more:

Nodes method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx

Value method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx